# Creating dynaimc controls in c# and placing them in html

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an datatable which I would like to use to generate controls i.e. 
**textbox, checkbox, dropdown**

From the datatable I need to create those controls using c#, can any one help me out in syntax. How do I go ahead and bind these controls in HTML tags?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

Your .aspx should contain, for example

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

As fort the .cs:

```
TextBox newBox = new TextBox();
newBox.ID = "newBox1";
newBox.Width = "50px";
... (Set style, absolute location if needed, etc)
newBox.Text = "This is a new dynamically created TB";
div1.Controls.Add(newBox);
```

A tiny note:
Adding dynamically-created controls can give you a really hard time, as you need to 're-create' them on each postback